# Packrat: Does the order of snapshotting vs. restoring matter?

Tags: r, packrat

Sometimes when working with **packrat**, one gets this kind of output whilst checking on the status of the packrat library:

```
> packrat::status()

The following packages are tracked by packrat, but are no longer available in the local library nor present in your code:
                _      
    viridisLite   0.2.0

You can call packrat::snapshot() to remove these packages from the lockfile, or if you intend to use these packages, use packrat::restore() to restore them to your private library.

The following packages have been updated in your library, but have not been recorded in packrat:
              library   packrat
    RSQLite       2.0        NA
    blob        1.1.0        NA
    formatR       1.5        NA

Use packrat::snapshot() to record these packages in packrat.

The following packages are out of sync between packrat and your current library:
                  packrat    library
    BH           1.65.0-1   1.60.0-2
    R6              2.2.2      2.2.0
    Rcpp          0.12.13     0.12.7
    Rfacebook      0.6.17     0.6.15
    assertthat      0.2.0        0.1
    backports       1.1.1      1.0.5
    colorspace      1.3-2      1.2-6
    curl              3.0        2.1
    dplyr           0.7.4      0.5.0
    htmltools       0.3.6      0.3.5
    httr            1.3.1      1.2.1
    jsonlite          1.5        1.4
    lazyeval        0.2.1      0.2.0
    openssl         0.9.8      0.9.4
    reshape2        1.4.2      1.4.1
    scales          0.5.0      0.4.1
    stringi         1.1.5      1.1.2
    tibble          1.3.4        1.2
    yaml           2.1.14     2.1.13

Use packrat::snapshot() to set packrat to use the current library, or use
packrat::restore() to reset the library to the last snapshot.
```

My question is: Which one should one run first, `restore()` or `snapshot()`? I have looked through the packrat documentation but there doesn't seem to be a way one could carry out parameterized updates i.e. to nitpick on packages.

**UPDATE:**
Following Alex's suggestion below, I received this prompt:

```
> packrat::restore()

Adding these packages to your library:
                _      
    viridisLite   0.2.0


Removing these packages from your library:
            _      
    RSQLite   2.0  
    blob      1.1.0
    formatR   1.5  
    memoise   1.1.0


Upgrading these packages in your library:
                     from         to
    BH           1.60.0-2   1.65.0-1
    R6              2.2.0      2.2.2
    Rcpp           0.12.7    0.12.13
    Rfacebook      0.6.15     0.6.17
    assertthat        0.1      0.2.0
    backports       1.0.5      1.1.1
    colorspace      1.2-6      1.3-2
    curl              2.1        3.0
    dplyr           0.5.0      0.7.4
    glue            1.1.1      1.2.0
    htmltools       0.3.5      0.3.6
    httr            1.2.1      1.3.1
    jsonlite          1.4        1.5
    lazyeval        0.2.0      0.2.1
    openssl         0.9.4      0.9.8
    reshape2        1.4.1      1.4.2
    rlang           0.1.1      0.1.4
    scales          0.4.1      0.5.0
    stringi         1.1.2      1.1.5
    tibble            1.2      1.3.4
    yaml           2.1.13     2.1.14

Do you want to continue? [Y/n]:
```

The answer is **No**.

What I want to do is to remove `viridislite`, not add it, and I want to add `RSQLite`, `blob` and `formatR` as suggested.

And now I'm also wondering how `memoise` came into the picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what do you want from `packrat`. If you want to load the last snapshot, use `restore()`. If you update a package that's used in project, and want to make new snapshot, use `snapshot()`.

Comment: In this instance, the project was fetched from a remote git repository and the packrat versions appear to have outstripped those in the local library...

Comment: In this case you should first use restore().